Round-trip equations of fields in a cavity with nonlinear medium (SPDC)
I'm having a lot of trouble trying to understand a set of equations corresponding to the dynamic of field operators of the signal and idler beam in a cavity where one places a non-linear crystal. The papers I found do not give a lot of details on how they obtained the mathematical equations. First here is a schema taken from [1] (figure 3.1):

The idea is to consider the loss in the cavity coming from a fictitious beam-splitter. Reference [1] then gives the following set of equations for the signal and idler beam fields after one round trip ($\tau$ is the time it takes to do one round-trip):
$$a_s(t + \tau) = (1 - T'/2)[a_s(t) + g a_p(t)a_i^\dagger(t)] + \sqrt{L} a_{s,L}(t) + \sqrt{T} a_{s,In}(t)$$
$$a_i(t+\tau) = (1 - T'/2)[a_i(t) + g a_p(t)a_s^\dagger(t)] + \sqrt{L} a_{i,L}(t) + \sqrt{T} a_{i,In}(t)$$
I found another paper [2] giving a similar treatment (in French though, cf section 4 and 5 or Part II) but I also don't really see how they obtained the equations. I understand how the fields equations are obtained from the non-linear parametric effect (partial derivatives of the fields on $z$), but I don't understand how to go from these to the time dependent equations.
I had the intuitions one would need the Hamiltonian of the system to write $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}a = [H, a]$, with the interaction Hamiltonian $H_{int} = i \frac{\hbar g}{2}a_s^\dagger a_i^\dagger a_p + h.c$ but I think there should be extra terms in the total Hamiltonian (like $\hbar \omega a^\dagger a$ for each field) but by doing so the calculations seem endless and I fail to reach the desired results.
I understand what the coefficient refers to and why we can simplify some square roots terms, it's really how to obtain the whole equation mathematically that I don't get. Plus, from the expression of the field after one round trip I just need to perform a Taylor expansion to get the derivatives expressions, so that's also not an issue.
[1] : https://theses.hal.science/tel-01066655
[2] : https://theses.hal.science/tel-00007442

I think you would indeed need the interaction Hamiltonian to calculate the commutator with the field operators, but then if you integrate that over the length of the crystal two times and you only keep the dominant field, then you'd find the term in $\mathfrak{g}$. I think if you write down all the transmitted and reflected fields with the proper coefficients you'll find the equations easily :)

I think this integration of the commutator term was the missing part because you're right, simply writing down the transmitted and reflected fields work nicely, it was just the interaction term that was missing thanks!

Just in case, make sure you integrate on the length 2L because it's going back and forth in the cavity ;)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
